# C++ - running on VS code with code runner

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, config, vscode-code-runner

I am trying to compile and run C++ programs on VS code. I have my compiler set up, and I am trying to use the terminal for taking the user input. I tried to change the settings config for code runner by updating the

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

After this, the terminal refuses to run the code. I understand the error that I am getting, but I have no clue on how I can fix it. Here is the program I am trying to run:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
   int x;
   cin >> x;
   cout << "Output:" << x;
}
```

The output I get after I try to run it is:

```
cd "d:\Github\problem-solving\HackerRank\Cpp\" && g++ pointers.cpp -o pointers && "d:\Github\problem-solving\HackerRank\Cpp\"pointers 
bash: cd: d:\Github\problem-solving\HackerRank\Cpp" && g++ pointers.cpp -o pointers && d:Githubproblem-solvingHackerRankCpp"pointers: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looking at the output the problem appears to be the \ character more specifically \ is being replaced with escape the next character similar to how it would escape a string literal in c++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have not set up your terminal root. Essentially, the code runner will try to look for a terminal root in contexts like these, and thus if it does not get one, it misreads the input file's name when you execute it. **Essentially, set the value for "code-runner".terminalRoot to "/" (without the quotes**). Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image]

**This should get your code running in no time!**